# Can't find package.json in directory in CircleCI build

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, circleci

I have a repo that contains **two subprojects**. Just for completeness a frontend project and a firebase cloud-function project (both using separate package.jsons). Now for this project, I want to start two jobs concurrently. But I can't get the setup done with CircleCI. I don't have any cache-configuration.

#### project structure

```
-creepy-stories
  -.circleci
  -cloud-functions
    -functions
     package.json
  -frontend
   package.json
```

#### config.yml

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  cloud-functions:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.8.0

    working_directory: ~/creepy-stories/cloud-functions/functions

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run lint
      - run: npm run build

  frontend:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.8.0

    working_directory: ~/creepy-stories/frontend
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run lint
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run test:coverage

workflows:
  version: 2
  cloud-functions_and_frontend:
    jobs:
      - cloud-functions
      - frontend
```

So now my I guess my problem is the environment cant find my package.json file. The error that is printed looks as follows:

#### npm run lint

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
npm run lint
npm ERR! path /home/circleci/creepy-stories/frontend/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/circleci/creepy-stories/frontend/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2019-04-20T13_08_45_252Z-debug.log
Exited with code 254
```

I don't know if it is right to set the working directory twice in my configuration, but it is at least set in two diff. jobs.

### Update

I managed to get it work if I checkout the root of the Project and then `cd` to the needed folder and execute the scripts. But this isn't really DRY (don't repeat yourself) maybe some of you have a better solution:

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  cloud-functions:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.8.0

    working_directory: ~/creepy-stories

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: cd cloud-functions/functions && npm install
      - run: cd cloud-functions/functions && npm run lint
      - run: cd cloud-functions/functions && npm run build

  web:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.8.0

    working_directory: ~/creepy-stories
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: cd web && npm install
      - run: cd web && npm run lint
      - run: cd web && npm run build
      - run: cd web && npm run test:coverage

workflows:
  version: 2
  concurrently:
    jobs:
      - cloud-functions
      - web
```

Comment: Do the jobs start concurrently? I guess that is the first thing. Do you have two build servers available (i.e. on a paid plan) to permit that?

Comment: You've reported the `npm run lint` for one of these jobs, did the `npm install` succeed for both of them? If not, would you post both outputs?

Comment: No I do not need to build servers for the CI process. And yes npm install did succeed.

Comment: _"No I do not need to build servers for the CI process"_. You've misunderstood my comment - I was asking if you had more than one CircleCI server to achieve the parallelism you are seeking.

Answer (score 4):

When you checkout, you automatically copy the root of the git repository into the current working directory. If you want your working directory to be a sub-directory of the root, you need to give the checkout step a path that copies the files into a parent of the working directory.

Example:

```
working_directory: ~/creepy-stories/cloud-functions
steps:
  - checkout:
      path: ~/creepy-stories
```

Link to the documentation: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#checkout

Comment: This setup gives me Directory (/home/circleci/creepy-stories) you are trying to checkout to is not empty and not a git repository. That's because cloud-functions folder exists in creepy-stories

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got an added directory in the way.

You should add an extra run to your CircleCi frontend task that does a `pwd` and then a `ls -la`.

You'll probably find that the checkout has ended up inside a directory with the same name as your repo.

Edit to answer followup question:

If i remember correctly, the checkout command, always put it in the root of the server, so you can update the working directory to accommodate that. Like so

```
    working_directory: ~/creepy-stories/web
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run lint
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run test:coverage
```